# How do I block access to Whatsapp application on my XRAY server?

Tags: networking, firewall, proxy, ip

I'm trying to block my XRAY server clients from accessing Whatsapp mobile application . I blocked a list of domains :

```
wa.me
whatsapp-plus.info
whatsapp-plus.me
whatsapp-plus.net
whatsapp.cc
whatsapp.com
whatsapp.info
whatsapp.net
whatsapp.org
whatsapp.tv
whatsappbrand.com
```

But still I can access the app normally . It seems their app is using other domains or IPs . How can I block traffic to whatsapp mobile application ?

Comment: well since you did not done for now some research or at least do not show it, I found a github project that may help https://github.com/ukanth/afwall/wiki/HOWTO-blocking-WhatsApp

Comment: I actually tried all the domains and IPs . didn't work and still I had traffic to whatsapp android and ios apps .

Answer (score 1):

After doing a lot of research and trial and error , the answer is you can't block whatsapp android and ios apps unless you block the whole internet or you have " the great firewall of China " . I blocked all IPs that facebook ( META ) owns but the app used Amazon IPs to load itself ! I blocked all Amazon IPs but the app used Google cloud IPs to load itself ! It seems the only way to block it is by DPI which GFW uses .

Comment: remind to accept your own answer

Comment: well there might be a option but for that it requires a strong mdm and apple products